# How to update a specific row from pivot table in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this model in Organization.php

```
public function agency()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Agency')->withPivot('status');
}
```

and this model in Agency.php

```
public function organizations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Organization')->withPivot('status');
}
```

How can I update the status of a specific row in my pivot table?
This is my code in the controller:

```
public function removeAgency(Request $request){
    $my_agencies = Organization::find($request['org_id']);
    $member = $my_agencies->agency()
        ->where('agency_organization.agency_id', $request['agency_id'])
            ->first();
    $member->pivot->status = 'removed';
    $member->pivot->save();
}
```

It returns an error saying: "Creating default object from empty value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [updateExistingPivot](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method.

```
Organization::find($request['org_id'])->agency()
    ->updateExistingPivot($request['agency_id'], ['status' => 'removed']);
```